# displaying notification only once from onprogressupdate method

Tags: android, notifications, async-onprogressupdate

I am trying to display a notification only once from an onprogress update method. There is condition which will allow the notification to be displayed. The problem is that it continues to display notifications after the first one and the phone keeps on ringing and vibrating. I want to receive only one notification informing about something and stop. Is is possible? can someone help please and suggest alternative ways of doing it. Thanks.

Here's my code for the onPorgressUpdate method:

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
         super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         String command=new String(values[0]);//get the String from the recieved bytes
         String[] parts= command.split(",");
         String part1=parts[0];
         String part2=parts[1];

         temp.setText(part1);
         humi.setText(part2);

         if(Integer.parseInt(part2)>70)
         {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context);
            builder.setContentTitle("AM Home Automation");
            builder.setContentText("humi");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setTicker("alert");
            builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean to remember you already showed the notification and use it to not show another one like below:

```
private boolean alreadyDisplayedNotification = false;

protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    String command=new String(values[0]);//get the String from the recieved bytes
    String[] parts= command.split(",");
    String part1=parts[0];
    String part2=parts[1];

    temp.setText(part1);
    humi.setText(part2);

    if(Integer.parseInt(part2)>70 && !alreadyDisplayedNotification) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context);
        builder.setContentTitle("AM Home Automation");
        builder.setContentText("humi");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTicker("alert");
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        alreadyDisplayedNotification=true;
    }
```

Comment: @akshay270494: glad, I could help

Comment: sir, how to add a delay of 20 seconds before the if loop is run again to check is it is still > 70 ? could you please help or suggest other ways

Comment: you can put Thread.sleep(20000) which is equal to 20 seconds at the end of the loop..

Comment: i added the line ... the onprogressupdate stopped updating the values and keep on sending notification every 20seconds

Comment: where did you put this line ?

Comment: inside the if statement just after the line "alreadyDiaplayedNotification=true" surrounded with try catch

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setOnlyAlertOnce(true) on notification builder, this will show heads up notification only once

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)sensitive content.
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(notiPriority)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true) // set this to show and vibrate only once
            .build();
```